# Manipulate data returned from an AJAX call in jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have an AJAX call using jQuery:

```
$('.add a').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/fos',
        context: this,
        datatype: 'html',
        success: function(data){
            $(this).parents('tr').before(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Once it runs, it adds a new row to a table. The row is verbatim to other rows in the table (structure-wise), but with no data.

I have two other jQuery calls that manipulates the data on the row, but the calls don't work on the new table rows using the AJAX call. Specifically, when a drop-down (select/option) list changes, it does an AJAX call to replace the contents of another drop-down list. Another function removes the row if you want to delete it.

These are the functions that are not working:

```
$('.fos').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax/courses',
        context: this,
        data:({
            fos_id: $(this).val(),
            name: $(this).find(':selected').text()
        }),
        success: function(data){
            $(this).next().html(data);
        }
    });
});

$('td.remove a').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
});
```

Does this have something to do with the AJAX call not registering the new row with DOM or can this not be done?

Answer (score 3):

When you run the code you have on document.ready, jQuery is literally binding the events to all the existing rows *at that point in time*. To make jQuery aware of possible DOM changes, you need to use jQuery's [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) functionality. To optimally do what you want, you probably want to use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) like so:

```
$("#yourTable").delegate("select.fos", "change", function(){
    // ....
});

$("#yourTable").delegate("td.remove a", "click", function(){
    // ....
});
```

The way it works is by binding the events to the selector (`#yourTable`) and letting the events bubble up to it, so that any modifications to the contents of the table are covered.